# Conditionally drop temporary table in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are using http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/ and I am creating/dropping temporary tables in reports.  Occasionally we encounter cases where someone has created a temporary table and failed to drop it.

In other databases, for instance PostgreSQL which Redshift is based on, I could simply:

`DROP TEMP TABLE IF EXISTS tblfoo;`

But that is a syntax error in Redshift.  I can check for the existence of temporary tables myself using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_TBL_PERM.html but that only works if I am a superuser and I am not running as a superuser.  I could also go and swallow exceptions, but with my reporting framework I'd prefer not to go there.

So how can I, as a regular user and without generating database errors, conditionally drop a temporary table if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test I ran showed that I could see other users' temp tables in stv_tbl_perm using a non-super user id.  The cluster version I tested in is 1.0.797.  Note that no users can see other users' temp tables in pg_class.

Comment: I swear, last week I got an error from `select * from stv_tbl_perm where temp = 1;` but now it seems to work.  Did that just get changed in Redshift??

Comment: Not sure.  Glad it works for you now.  Def would like the "if exists" functionality to get built in.