# How RedShift Sessions are handled from a Server Connection for TEMP tables

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-redshift

I'm using ColdFusion to connect to a RedShift database and I'm trying to understand how to test/assume myself of how the connections work in relation to TEMP tables in RedShift.

1. In my CFADMIN for the datasource I have **unchecked** `Maintain connections across client requests`. I would assume then each user who is using my website would have their own "Connection" to the DB? Is that correct?
2. Per the RedShift docs about temp tables:

> TEMP: Keyword that creates a temporary table that is visible only within the current session. The table is automatically dropped at the end of the session in which it is created. The temporary table can have the same name as a permanent table. The temporary table is created in a separate, session-specific schema. (You cannot specify a name for this schema.) This temporary schema becomes the first schema in the search path, so the temporary table will take precedence over the permanent table unless you qualify the table name with the schema name to access the permanent table.

Am I to understand that if #1 is true and each user has their own connection to the database and thereby their own session then per #2 any tables that are created will be only in that session even though the "user" is the same as it's a connection from my server that is using the same credentials.

3.If my assumptions in #1 and #2 are correct then if I have ColdFusion code that runs a query like so:

```
drop if exists tablea
create temp table tablea
insert into tablea
select * from realtable inner join
drop tablea
```

And multiple users are using that same function that does this. They should never run into any conflicts where one table gets dropped as another request is trying to use it correct?

4. How do I test that this is the case? Besides throwing it into production and waiting for an error how can I know. I tried running a few windows side by side in different browsers and stuff and didn't notice an issue, but I don't know how to know if the temp tables truly are different between clients. (as they should be.) I imagine I could query some meta data but what meta data about the table would tell me that?

Comment: When I query `stv_sessions` I can see multiple session for my username.

Comment: Disclaimer, I am not familiar with redshift, but what you describe is how (non-global) temp tables behave in databases like SQL Server. The same "user" can create multiple sessions, but temp table created in one session are not visible to the other sessions. Not sure if this helps, but [this thread mentions checking STV_TBL_PERM](BNohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561837/conditionally-drop-temporary-table-in-redshift).

Comment: Do you know about the connection from the server to the DB. The setting in CF I spoke about seems to indicate that each client request (not sure what that definition is) would have a unique connection and as a result unique session right?

Comment: Correct. When "maintain connections" is disabled, each request should create a new connection, which constitutes a separate db "session".

Comment: If that is true, then I assume then a single session is active and CF keeps open until the timeout for a particular user. So `usera` logs into my app and actively uses it for an hour. They could have had a single session for an hour. `userb` logs into my app and only does stuff every 25 minutes. Since my datasource connection timeout is 20 minutes they would have a different DB session for every time.

Comment: No, that really describes what happens when connection pooling is *enabled*. CF maintains a pool of open DB connections. They are left open in the pool until the defined "Timeout" in the CF Admin. Periodically, CF checks for unused connections that exceed the timeout and closes them  ie "Interval (min)" . When connection pooling is *disabled*, a new request is opened as needed, and closed when the request is finished with it.

Comment: So then how are there active sessions that I can see in RedShift for my username that are longer than just a few seconds. It seems like all of the sessions would be very very short.

Comment: (Edit) Honestly I do not know how RedShift's internal session tables are handled. However, with a SQL Server DSN connections are very short lived when connection pooling is disabled, like you would expect. ie Generate X requests (which all execute a query), see X sessions opened. When the requests end, all X sessions are closed shortly thereafter. Are you sure connection pooling was disabled in the DSN?

Comment: What happened when you checked STV_TBL_PERM as mentioned above? The docs suggest [this query for obtaining a listing of table names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html). *"...The current session's temporary-table schema, pg_temp_nnn (or pg_temp for short).."*. If run that query in different sessions, each containing the same #temp table name, it should return only one (1) record with that temp table `#temp`, but with a different table id in each session.

Comment: Everything I've tried to test and see I don't see duplicate tables. So I think I'm fine. I'm going to run it in prod but as a beta test so some people can put it under load and see if anything strange happens. All my tests seem to indicate it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but with redbrick database software.  I handle it by creating unique table names.  The general idea is:

1. Create a table name something like this:

   ```
   <cfset tablename = TableText & randrange(1, 100000)>
   ```
2. Try to create a table with that name.  If you fail try again with a different name.
3. If you fail 3 times stop trying and mail the cfcatch information to someone.

I have all this code in a custom tag.

**Edit starts here**

Based on the comments, here is some more information about my situation.  In CFAdmin, for the datasource being discussed, the Maintain Connections box is checked.

I put this code on a ColdFusion page:

```
<cfquery datasource="dw">
create temporary table dan (f1 int)
</cfquery>
```

I ran the page and then refreshed it.  The page executed successfully the first time.  When refreshed, I got this error.

```
Error Executing Database Query.  
** ERROR ** (7501) Name defined by CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE already exists.
```

That's why I use unique tablenames.  I don't cache the queries though.  Ironically, my most frequent motivation for using temporary tables is because there are situations where they make things run faster than using the permanent tables.

Comment: Doesn't redbrick support true temp tables? (I have never used it)

Comment: Redbrick termporary tables are explained here.  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCRW7_6.3.0/com.ibm.redbrick.doc6.3/sqlrg/sqlrg67.htm.  `It is exclusive to the SQL session in which it is created`  My interpretation of a session wrt CF is that it is a connection between the CF server and the redbrick database.  I also make the assumption that an open connection can be used on more than one page request.

Comment: I thought about doing unique table names as well. But here is the problem. I cache the overall query for 30 minutes for performance purposes. If the names are truly unique with each function call, then the query would be unique as well and as such caching wouldn't work. I guess I could possibly do a `cachePut` and do it that way, but adding the `cachedWithin` works better as there are other params within the query that can change and `cachedwithin` takes that into account.,

Comment: Dan - Thanks. It sounds similar to (non-global) temp table handling in SQL Server. As far as connections, they may be reused by multiple requests *if* connection pooling is used. Otherwise, each request should create a separate connection or db "session". Though I have never seen it documented, AFAIK a single request usually maintains the same connection or "session" for the entire request. In other words, if you request a page that runs five (5) queries, CF should use the same connection for all five queries, rather than creating a separate connection for each query.

Comment: (Edit) Dan - I think you are misunderstanding how temp tables and database sessions are supposed to work.  You *should* get an error when maintain connections is *enabled*. When using connection pooling existing db connections are reused. That means multiple requests can share the same db session. Therefore temp tables may be visible from one request to the next, which is what you are seeing above. However, when pooling is *disabled*, each connection creates a new db session and any temp tables created are NOT be visible from one request to the next.